# How do I Encrypt a Flash Drive Using SecurStick?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, encryption

I am trying to use SecurStick to encrypt a flash drive. I found these [instructions](http://www.ampercent.com/usb-flash-drive-encryption-software/5757/) online. However, when I unzip the archive and place the files on my flash drive, I cannot run the SecurStick program from the drive.

It works fine if I just run it from my home folder. I think it may be some sort of permissions problem, but I'm not sure.

I am running Peppermint.

Comment: Maybe the stick is mounted using `noexec` flag. Use `mount` to check. I would avoid this program regardless, even if it works, it's so badly documented... and not open source, either?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will checkout LUKS as recommended by Lucas.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with frostschutz's comment. This program seems to be lacking a lot of documentation and it looks like the *nix version is just a port of the Winodws version. I would recommend using something like LUKS encryption. Here is a guide for setting up LUKS encryption on a [USB drive](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/encrypting-data-on-usb-flash-drives-with-luks/).